# Kotlin: Is there a tool that allows me to control parallelism when executing suspend functions?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing, akka

I'm trying to execute certain suspend function multiple times, in such a way that never more than N of these are being executed at the same time.

For those acquainted with Akka and Scala Streaming libraries, something like `mapAsync`.

I did my own implementation using one input channel (as in kotlin channels) and N output channels. But it seems cumbersome and not very efficient.

The code I'm currently using is somewhat like this:

```kotlin
val inChannel = Channel<T>()
val outChannels = (0..n).map{
  Channel<T>()
}
launch{
   var i = 0
   for(t in inChannel){
     
     outChannels[i].offer(t)
     i = ((i+1)%n)
   }
}
outChannels.forEach{outChannel ->
  launch{
     for(t in outChannel){
        fn(t)
     }
  }
}
```

Of course it has error management and everything, but still...

Edit: I did the following test, and it failed.

```kotlin
test("Parallelism is correctly capped") {
            val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default.limitedParallelism(3))
            var num = 0
            (1..100).map {
                scope.launch {
                    num ++
                    println("started $it")
                    delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
                }
            }

            delay(500)
            assertEquals(3,num)

        }
```

Comment: Please share the code you want to use this in so that we have more context regarding intended use-case.

Comment: @tkroman I added some code

Comment: Using a simple integer `var` to test parallelism should be avoided, it is not thread-safe. Even with only 3 coroutines running in parallel, there is no guarantee that `num` will be incremented correctly. But here, 100 launch can run concurrently. When one launch reaches the delay, another coroutines can take over and increment. `delay()` is non-blocking, it won't hold on to the thread - that's the whole point! If you want to avoid concurrency (not parallelism), then either launch less coroutines or use a semaphore around the coroutine's code that you want "atomic"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question, as asked, calls for @marstran's answer. If what you want is that no more than N coroutines are being actively executed *at any given time* (in parallel), then `limitedParallelism` is the way to go:

```kotlin
val maxThreads: Int = TODO("some max number of threads")
val limitedDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default.limitedParallelism(maxThreads)

elements.forEach { elt ->
    scope.launch(limitedDispatcher) {
        doSomething(elt)
    }
}
```

Now, if what you want is to even limit *concurrency*, so that at most N coroutines are run concurrently (potentially interlacing), regardless of threads, you could use a [Semaphore](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-semaphore/index.html) instead:

```kotlin
val maxConcurrency: Int = TODO("some max number of concurrency coroutines")
val semaphore = Semaphore(maxConcurrency)

elements.forEach { elt ->
    scope.async {
        semaphore.withPermit {
            doSomething(elt)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also combine both approaches.

Comment: the problem with `withPermit` is that only non-suspend functions are accepted.

Comment: @AlejandroNavas what makes you think this? The function is inline, it does accept suspend functions. https://pl.kotl.in/hcIa-8x8z

Comment: This is probably a habit acquired when dealing with threads, but I always feel like a queue of 1000 items and 8 consumers is better for performance than 1000 coroutines waiting for a permit. I assume coroutines don't fight each other for these permits, they are also formed into a queue of some sort, but still, I usually avoid such solutions. On the other hand, I consider semaphore to be a cleaner approach and it allows for synchronous execution of tasks, contrary to a queue. Do you know of any benchmarks that compare both solutions? I would like to be proven wrong :-)

Comment: @Joffrey, you're right. But i learned something. `withPermit(fn)` doesn't compile but `withPermit{fn()}` does...

Comment: @broot I honestly don't have any benchmark for this, but my assumption would be that they perform similarly. As you said, either you have an explicit queue of items, or you have a queue of coroutines. Maybe there is a slight overhead in the coroutines due to their state machine. In any case, I would probably choose depending on the context of what I'm doing. I haven't ever needed a semaphore to be honest :)

Comment: @AlejandroNavas this is due to how inlining works. A `suspend` function reference is not a valid non-suspend function, so you can't pass it directly this way. But it's possible to pass a lambda with suspend calls inside because it's inlined and the suspend "constraint" propagates to the caller instead

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `limitedParallelism`-function on a `Dispatcher` (experimental in v1.6.0), and use the returned dispatcher to call your asynchronous functions. The function returns a view over the original dispatcher which limits the parallelism to a limit you provide. You can use it like this:

```
val limit = 2 // Or some other number

val dispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
val limitedDispatcher = dispatcher.limitedParallelism(limit)

for (n in 0..100) {
    scope.launch(limitedDispatcher) {
        executeTask(n)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with limitedParallelism is that it limits the number of threads. Not the number of... let's say... fibers. One single thread can still have multiple suspended threads concurrently waiting.

Comment: As far as I understand, it will only run at most `limit` number of coroutines at the same time. As the documentation says: `The resulting view uses the original dispatcher for execution, but with the guarantee that no more than parallelism coroutines are executed at the same time.`.

Comment: You can also read more about it in the blog post where they introduced it: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/introducing-kotlinx-coroutines-1-6-0/#dispatcher-views-api

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already explained that it depends whether you need to limit parallelism or concurrency. If you need to limit concurrency, then you can do this similarly to your original solution, but with only a single channel:

```kotlin
val channel = Channel<T>()
repeat(n) {
    launch {
        for(t in channel){
            fn(t)
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that `offer()` in your example does not guarantee that the task will be ever executed. If the next consumer in the round robin is still occupied with the previous task, the new task is simply ignored.